# Handle AuthenticationException in Spring 5 with custom authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm trying to define a default entry point for handling `AuthenticationException`.

This is my configuration:

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .cors()
            .and()
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
        .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
        .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler())
            .permitAll();
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler() {
    return new RestAuthenticationFailureHandler();
}
```

I have set the `AuthenticationFailureHandler` which from what I understand handles all of the `AuthenticationException`. But instead the `SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler` is being called.

What am I doing wrong? I have read almost 30 posts in SO with no good answer.

I also tried to use a custom `AuthenticationEntryPoint` and it works but I don't get the original exception, only a generic exception that doesn't help me at all.

I am using Spring 5.

If there is missing information please let me know. I believe I am sharing the relevant code since it seems a configuration issue. The AuthenticationException is being thrown after I call the `authenticate()` method inside my `JWTAuthenticationFilter`.

Comment: The method is part of the [`FormLoginConfigurer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.7.RELEASE/api/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this doesn't work at all because I'm using  **custom authentication**:

```
.formLogin()
        .failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler())
```

Instead, I had to set the AuthenticationFailureHandler inside the constructor of my UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter like this:

```
public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {
  private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

  public JWTAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
      this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
      this.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(new RestAuthenticationFailureHandler());
  }
}
```

I hope I am helping someone with my own answer.

Comment: No, your answer isn't wrong, except *at all*, replace it with "for custom authentication".

Comment: I edited both the title and the answer accordingly. Thank you for your time and help.